# How can I query the MySQL Max_Allowed_Packet through c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, max-allowed-packet

I am trying to check the value of the `max_allowed_packet` size. This is my code:

```
public int MaxAllowedPacket()
{                
    var max = 0;
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
    {
        var sql = conn.CreateCommand();
        sql.CommandText = "SHOW VARIABLES like 'max_allowed_packet'";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            var reader = sql.ExecuteReader();
            // not sure where to go from here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // I've got some logging here
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I'm suspecting the format of the query or the execution is wrong because my result is always

> -1

**EDIT:**

I have edited the code to use `sql.ExecuteReader()` but the result is now:

> "Enumeration yielded no results".

Comment: running executenonquery, doesnt return data - so ... you cant ask for "select stuff" to return you values.

Comment: @BugFinder Thank you. I have changed it to `sql.ExecuteReader();` but the query returns "Enumeration yielded no results". What is the right way to read the value?

Comment: if you just expect one single value back, then ExecuteScalar is probably easier to work with

Comment: @ADyson ExecuteScalar only seems to return the very first value, in this case the string `"max_allowed_packet"`.

Comment: @ToshiBoy No problem, I wasn't sure exactly what it would return. Your answer is right, with a DataReader you have to execute the Read() command to move to the first line (and then execute it again to move to subsequent lines - people usually put `while (reader.Read()) { ... }` to read all rows in a multi-row resultset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually figured it out myself, and thought to post it here, before this gets downvoted even more...

```
var reader = sql.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
max = reader.GetInt32(1);
```

It's best to put some try catches around and you can optionally query the first field through `reader.GetString(0)`, which should return "max_allowed_packet".